# how to get total number of records retrieved with pagination on the current page using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

in my code currently i am showing 2 records per page and their are total 10 pages showing data , i want that it should display total items like this in the header :
1-2 of 10 means record number 1,2 out of 10 record and when i click next button it should show me another record like 3-4 of 10 . i am not getting any clue how to do this , nothing of this kind is given on the angular tutorials , kindly help me out.

this is my code for pagination in html:

```
 <pagination page="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" total-items="totalItems"
                            items-per-page="entryLimit" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" style="cursor:pointer">
                        </pagination>
```

here is my controller logic:

```
                          $scope.currentPage = 1;
                          $scope.maxSize = 2;
                          $scope.totalLeadItems = $scope.finalLeadData.dataval;
                          $scope.totalItems = $scope.finalLeadData.dataval.length;
                          $scope.entryLimit = 2; // items per page
                          $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);

                         $scope.search = function (item){
                          //console.log(item.LEAD_NM);
                          return !! ((angular.lowercase(item.LEAD_NM).indexOf($scope.search.LEAD || '') !== -1 || angular.lowercase(item.LEAD_MBL).indexOf($scope.search.LEAD || '') !== -1));

                            };


                          //$watch search to update pagination
                          $scope.$watch('search.LEAD', function (newVal) {
                              $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.finalLeadData.dataval, newVal);
                              $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
                              $scope.noOfPages =  Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
                              $scope.currentPage = 1;

                          }, true);
                      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this calculation in the dom:

```
{{ currentPage * entryLimit - 1 }} - {{ currentPage * entryLimit }} of {{ totalLeadItems.length }}
```

Comment: yuhuuu you saved my day its working fine thanks buddy :)

Comment: Glad to help, upvote and accept the answer please :)

Comment: i have some issue with this logic , if i have odd number of data  for eg: i have total items as 123 , then it is showing me like : 123-124 of 123 . which is not right . kindly tell me how to resolve this logical issue.